# jQuery .trim() IE Browser Compatibility Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I tested the following in FF, OP, Chrome, Safari and IE. It works in them all except the 3 IEs I tested: 8, 7, and 6.

```
// truncate testimonial 
var visiblePara = $('div.bannerUnder p.show');
if (visiblePara.text().trim().length > 150) {
    var text = visiblePara.text().trim();
    var author = $('div.bannerUnder p.show > strong').text();
    text = text.substr(0, 150) + "...";
    visiblePara.text(text).append("<strong>" + author + "</strong>");
}
```

It says:

Object doesn't support this property or method and points to this line:

```
if (visiblePara.text().trim().length > 150) {
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: @Patrick: `length` is a property, not a function.

Comment: @Chuck: You changed the title to "jQuery .length IE Browser Compatibility Question" but this is not about .length – it is about .trim() not available in IE before version 8.

Comment: Good catch. I'll change the function to .trim(), but I'm trying to leave the question title in the context of how he was initially asking it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try changing:

```
visiblePara.text().trim().length
```

to:

```
$.trim(visiblePara.text()).length
```

You can even move the text variable up, with something like this:

```
// truncate testimonial 
var visiblePara = $('div.bannerUnder p.show');
var text = $.trim(visiblePara.text());
if (text.length > 150) {
    var author = $('div.bannerUnder p.show > strong').text();
    text = text.substr(0, 150) + "...";
    visiblePara.text(text).append("<strong>" + author + "</strong>");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

trim is not a method of String.prototype until IE 8. It has existed in other browsers for a while now.

I tried it in IE8 and it worked for me. Use [jQuery.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) `jQuery.trim(str)`
instead